# php display api search

Tags: php, html

I'm new to this just wondering how i can make this search display the info from api.
example api
https://example/v2/player/someidhere Also say we can call ID,NAME,AVATAR how do i display it.
this is the search i have so far.

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
  <input name="id" value="544531">
  <button>Send</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure what i'd need to do in the test.php to display the info called from the api.

Comment: You have a small bit of HTML and what you want to do involves using htaccess and mod_rewrite, a database, php code, not to mention security and several other (more) advanced programming techniques. I suggest you start by studying these languages and _earn your swimming certificate before you dive into the deep!_ Otherwise you'll simply drown.

Comment: yeah well this question is so unclear, I can't even see light shine through, not to mention too broad.

Comment: So you've just downloaded some code that works perfectly fine. Yet here you are asking help with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all this line:

```
<input name="id" value="544531">
```

has not a specified type, if you want it to be a visible text field, then use type="text" if you don't want the user to see the field, use type="hidden"

Lets assume that you changed the button and input field to the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="544531" />
<input type="submit" name="someName" />
```

Then you could proceed and fetch the data from the api by doing something like this:

```
/* Check if button was clicked */
if (isset($_POST['someName'])) {

    /* If id is empty or not a number, then don't proceed fetching data */
    if (empty($_POST['id']) || !is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
        echo 'Invalid id';

    } else {

        /* Fetch data */
        $data = file_get_contents('https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/' . $_POST['id']);

        /* Decode json */
        $data = json_decode($data, true);

        /* Dump data */
        print_r($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: The url is: https://api.truckersmp.com/v2/player/ change it in the code and it should work.

Comment: @AndrewLarsen that person's track record isn't so hot; as I stated in comments. Wishing you well on this one. Sorry I can't upvote, I've none left for today.

Comment: ok it worked thanks, But how can i limit it to display only what i want as it's displaying everything like how can i limit it to display the id and name only

Comment: Please take discussions to a chat room or [meta]. Comments are not the place.